# How to position items in material-ui appbar

Tags: material-ui

At the moment I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from 'material-ui';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const style = {
  flexGrow: 1,
};

const NavBar = ({ classes }) => (
  <div style={style}>
    <AppBar position="static" elevation={0} className={classes.appBar}>
      <Toolbar>
        <Link exact to="/">
          <Typography variant="title" className={classes.navLink}>
            Title
          </Typography>
        </Link>
        <Link exact to="/about" className={classes.navLink}>
          <Typography variant="title">
            about
          </Typography>
        </Link>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </div>
);

export default NavBar;
```

```
const styles = () => ({
  appBar: {
    background: 'transparent',
    color: 'black',
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
  navLink: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
  },
});

export default styles;
```

That code creates an AppBar that looks like the below. Notice the cramped links.

[image]

How can I style the AppBar so that the links are positioned like below? The material-ui documentation doesn't seem to have anything on positioning things in the AppBar.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using just Toolbar and position your title and links using flexbox? AppBar is a very limited with customization of its children

Comment: @AlexSanchez I'll give that a go.

Comment: That worked better. Thanks @AlexSanchez